# How can I update the script from limit to weight? Lua

Tags: lua, fivem

I use this ambulance job that is made in Lua. Unfortunately, being an old script, it's not updated, so it was still set to use "limit" which I changed to "weight" since my gamemode is based on weight as well as the database. But sadly it doesn't work, I get this error.

```
    RegisterServerEvent('esx_ambulancejob:giveItem')
AddEventHandler('esx_ambulancejob:giveItem', function(itemName)
    local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(source)

    if xPlayer.job.name ~= 'ambulance' then
        print(('esx_ambulancejob: %s attempted to spawn in an item!'):format(xPlayer.identifier))
        return
    elseif (itemName ~= 'medikit' and itemName ~= 'bandage') then
        print(('esx_ambulancejob: %s attempted to spawn in an item!'):format(xPlayer.identifier))
        return
    end

    local xItem = xPlayer.getInventoryItem(itemName)
    local count = 1

    if xItem.weight ~= -1 then (it was xItem.limit before)
        count = xItem.weight - xItem.count
    end

    if xItem.count < xItem.weight then
        xPlayer.addInventoryItem(itemName, count)
    else
        TriggerClientEvent('esx:showNotification', source, _U('max_item'))
    end
end)
```

The error screen when I try to take the item from the pharmacy:

[Console Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svRXz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which line is 263, but error says `object_name.weight is nil`.

Watching code, xItem doen't have field weight `(xItem.weight = nil)`.

Comment: What I posted is the entire piece of code that executes that function. Anyway, line 263 is this "count = xItem.weight - xItem.count"

Answer (score 0):

error is on this line

```
    if xItem.weight ~= -1 then (it was xItem.limit before)
        count = xItem.weight - xItem.count
    end
```

for knoing what value is null, you can make, just before a print like this

```
print("Test: " .. tostring(xItem.weith) .. " - " .. tostring(xItem.count);
```

But, i think that your operation is false becouse you do

```
xItem.weight - xItem.count;
```

maybe you want to make

```
xItem.weight * xItem.count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to check if your ESX framework is updated. It could possibly be outdated hence returning a non-existent field metadata. Check your database "items" table data. You should have a weight column there.